# Is that group abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a group and $N$ is its normal subgroup, such that every subgroup of $N$ is normal in $G$ and $C_G(N)\subset N $. Is $\frac{G}{N}$ always abelian?

I do not know such $G$ and $N$ where it is not, but neither I know general proof of this statement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $C_G (N)$? And does $\frac{G}{N}$ mean the quotient group of $G$ modulo $N$? My book writes the latter as $G/N$.

Comment: @yanko How does that help with the question posed here?

Comment: @yanko His notation is perfectly clear to me, whereas your comment looks somewhat random.

Comment: @Tobias, I'll delete it then, can you explain whats $C_G(N)$ then?

Comment: $C_G(N)$ is the centralizer of $N$ in $G$ (i.e. those elements of $G$ that commute with everything in $N$).

Comment: This is a well known algebra qualifying exam question, i.e., exercise $24$ [here](http://www.math.kent.edu/~white/qual/list/group.pdf). The answer is yes. Solutions are available.

Comment: @Dietrich, could you provide me with a link to the solutions, please.

Comment: @Yanior: let $n \in N$, and consider $H=\langle n \rangle$. This subgroup of $N$ is normal in $G$, so by the $N/C$ normalizer/centralizer theorem $G/C_G(H)$ embeds in $Aut(H)$, which is abelian, since $H$ is cyclic. Hence, $G' \subseteq C_G(H)$, in particluar $G' \subseteq C_G(n)$. Since $C_G(N)=\bigcap_{n \in N}C_G(n)$, this yields $G' \subseteq N$, that is, $G/N$ is abelian.